# Resolve dependencies of an arbitrary Debian or Ubuntu package

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, debian, package-managers

Given an arbitrary Debian or Ubuntu package (specified via a [PURL](https://github.com/package-url/purl-spec) such as `pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.50.3-1?arch=i386&distro=jessie`), I'm hoping to resolve the package's full dependency graph including:

- What packages would need to be installed to support the given package at run-time
- Which packages come from 'Depends', 'PreDepends', 'Suggests', etc.
- What is the full graph of relationships for all of those packages (which packages depend on which, which are 'direct' versus 'transitive' relative to the input package)
- For all of these 'resolved' package dependencies, what is the relevant version constraint *and* what is the latest stable version that would be installed via a package manager on a target system

This sort of information is available for packages in other ecosystems such as PyPi and NPM, both from native tooling and from external data aggregators such as [deps.dev](https://deps.dev/pypi/requests/2.31.0/dependencies) and [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/pypi/requests/2.31.0/tree), but I haven't been able to find any equivalents for Debian-based systems.

I'm able to get this information using commands such as `apt-cache policy <pkg_name>` and `apt-rdepends <pkg_name>`, but only if I execute them on a system backed by the same architecture and distribution as the package that I'm interested in. It also gets tripped up by the packages that I've already installed on the system, which can make the results 'skewed' or truncated and not contain the entire list of necessary dependencies and latest-stable versions. I'm hoping to find a way to get this information without requiring my running system to match the given package.

My current thought is that I'll need to parse, store, and query the package dependency information from the various Debian distributions myself (most likely parsing the `Packages` archives provided by the distribution, such as [this one](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-all/Packages.gz) for Debian Bookwork), but ideally there is a more off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: There are negative (Breaks, Conflicts) and sideways (Replaces, Provides) dependencies. Apt is using a SAT solver to figure out valid solutions to installing packages and can be persuaded to [solve a sudoku puzzle](https://games.slashdot.org/story/08/08/24/008201/solving-sudoku-with-dpkg) with a bunch of specially prepared packages and their dependencies. Your view of dependencies as a tree not depending on what is installed may be oversimplifying things a bit. [Why do you want to do this, anyway?](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @teapot418 Your concerns are acknowledged and I'm considering those in my solution. My use case of this is for 'low-effort, fast, generic' SBOM dependency graph resolution. I'm trying to identify places in a given SBOM where the most likely run-time dependencies are missing so that I can warn users of potential downstream/upstream security issues that they may be overlooking. I understand that determining the 100% accurate run-time SBOM is more complicated than what I'm attempting, but I believe the concept I'm looking at will help fill obvious gaps.